# MySQL - Aggregating Data from List of Events, Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm hoping someone can read through this scenario and the query I've created, and suggest an alternate method to get the same results.  I imagine some kind of conditional logic in the query would be useful -

The scenario is, I'm dealing with only 1 table, 'rto_events' which has records detailing the changes a 'Ticket' goes through as it moves between 'resolvers' or queues.  When a ticket is created, changes resolvers, or closes, a record is stored here detailing the changes.  The Incidentnbr is the ticket's unique identifier, but since they go through multiple changes in this table I'm also using an autonumber ID.

An example of the data in it :

```
|  id  |   date_of_event   |  incidentnbr  |  event_type      | new_resovler_group  |
| 110  |   04/01/2014      |  1234000      |  Opened          | Bob's Queue         |
| 111  |   04/01/2014      |  1235323      |  Opened          | Jim's Queue         |
| 112  |   04/02/2014      |  1234000      |  Changed Resolver| Jim's Queue         |
| 113  |   04/02/2014      |  1235323      |  Closed          | Jim's Queue         |
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `rto_events` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Date_of_event` datetime NOT NULL,
`IncidentNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Event_Type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`New_Resolver_Group` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

So I'm trying to generate a report showing what each queue looked like for a given day, which means considering a.) when a ticket was opened, b.) when it was closed, and c.) what is the most recent queue name for that ticket that is still before the given day.

Here is what I have come up with, and it produces the desired output.  My concerns are it is a little slow with just a few thousand records in it and this table may get very large, it is kind of ugly and unweildy, and there is likely a much easier way to do it.

I'm afraid I've committed a crime against SQL with this, and I'm hoping someone can point me in a better direction.  Any specific function, recommendation of a new layout or approach, what type of conditional logic to use -- anything that gets me started to optimize this I would greatly appreciate, I am not asking for someone to rewrite this for me.

First, create a collection of all opened tickets, and all closed tickets with an added "IsClosed" field, then union the two together:

```
(SELECT incidentnbr FROM rto_events 
        WHERE event_type = "Opened" AND date_of_event <= '$myDate') AS allcreated
LEFT JOIN 
(Select incidentnbr, TRUE AS isclosed FROM rto_events 
        WHERE event_type = "Closed" AND date_of_event <= '$myDate') AS allclosed
ON allcreated.incidentnbr = allclosed.incidentnbr
```

Wrapped around that, we select the incidentnbr from all fields without the isclosed tag, so we have a list of all open tickets created before the given date.

```
(SELECT allcreated.incidentnbr FROM 
     #Above snippet is imbedded in here
WHERE isclosed IS NULL) AS allopened
```

Now wrapped around that, we pull the associated Autonumber ID (To order the events to find the most recent) and the incidentnbr (So we can GROUP BY it in a moment, effectively collapsing it into the most recent ticket created for that incidentnbr)

```
(SELECT rto_events.id, allopened.incidentnbr FROM rto_events INNER JOIN
     #Above snippet imbedded here
ON rto_events.incidentnbr = allopened.incidentnbr 
WHERE rto_events.date_of_event <= '$myDate' 
ORDER BY id DESC) AS ordered
```

Now take that result and collapse it to the most recent record that is still prior to the given date for a ticket that was open on that given date:

```
(SELECT ordered.id, ordered.incidentnbr, new_resolver_group FROM rto_events INNER JOIN 
    #Above snippet is embedded here
ON rto_events.id = ordered.id GROUP BY incidentnbr) as mostrecentrecord
```

So now we have a list of one record per incidentnbr, where that record was created before the given date, was not closed before the given date, and is the most recent record up to and including the given date but not after.  It looks something like --

```
id    |    incidentnbr    |   new_resolver_group
1001  |    1252000        |   Tom's Queue
3042  |    1352104        |   Bill's Queue
9181  |    1125412        |   Jim's Queue
```

So the last thing left to do is aggregate it with a COUNT() function.

```
SELECT '$myDate' as incidentdate, new_resolver_group, count(new_resolver_group) as openedtickets FROM 
    #Above segment inbedded here
GROUP BY incidentdate, new_resolver_group;
```

So that's all of the SQL - here it is compiled:

```
SELECT '$myDate' as incidentdate, new_resolver_group, count(new_resolver_group) as openedtickets FROM 
        #Most Recent Record for Open Tickets START#
        (SELECT ordered.id, ordered.incidentnbr, new_resolver_group FROM rto_events INNER JOIN 
                        #Ordered Open Ticket IDs START#
                        (SELECT rto_events.id, allopened.incidentnbr FROM rto_events INNER JOIN 
                                        #All Opened Ticket Incident Numbers START#
                                        (SELECT allcreated.incidentnbr FROM 
                                                        (SELECT incidentnbr FROM rto_events 
                                                                        WHERE event_type = "Opened" AND date_of_event <= '$myDate') AS allcreated
                                        LEFT JOIN 
                                                        (Select incidentnbr, TRUE AS isclosed FROM rto_events 
                                                                        WHERE event_type = "Closed" AND date_of_event <= '$myDate') AS allclosed
                                        ON allcreated.incidentnbr = allclosed.incidentnbr
                                        WHERE isclosed IS NULL) AS allopened
                                        #All Opened Ticket Incident Numbers END#
                        ON rto_events.incidentnbr = allopened.incidentnbr 
                        WHERE rto_events.date_of_event <= '$myDate' 
                        ORDER BY id DESC) AS ordered
                        #Ordered Open Ticket IDs END#
        ON rto_events.id = ordered.id GROUP BY incidentnbr) as mostrecentrecord
        #Most Recent Record for Open Tickets END#
GROUP BY incidentdate, new_resolver_group;
```

Results :

```
incidentdate | new_resolver_group | count_of
04/01/2014   | Bob's Queue        | 32
04/01/2014   | Jim's Qeueue       | 16
```

If you've had experience with a similar problem and could offer some guidance I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions:
*a.) when a ticket was opened, b.) when it was closed, and c.) what is the most recent queue name for that ticket that is still before the given day.*

There's a simple solution for A and B, C is a bit more trickier (if I understood the question correctly).For the best results (regarding question C) it would be better to use some kind of a window functions (read about emulating those kind of functions with MySQL from here - http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=2).

Anyway, here is my solution (without the proper window function for question C, though).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
rt.incidentnbr
,dates.closed_date
,dates.open_date
,most_recent.new_resolver_group

FROM rto_events rt

LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    incidentnbr
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN event_type='Closed' THEN CAST(date_of_event AS DATE) END) closed_date -- given that there is only one closing date
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN event_type='Opened' THEN CAST(date_of_event AS DATE) END) open_date -- given that there is only one open date
    ,MAX(date_of_event) AS max_datetime
    FROM rto_events
    GROUP BY 1
    ) dates ON rt.incidentnbr=dates.incidentnbr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    incidentnbr
    ,date_of_event
    ,new_resolver_group
    FROM rto_events
    ) most_recent ON rt.incidentnbr=date.incidentnbr 
                  AND rt.date_of_event=dates.max_datetime
```

You can play around with it if it doesn't work (just remove the second left join section and new_resolver_group, because I have a feeling that it might not work as i'm expecting.. in that case you should read more about window functions in MySQL.

In some SQL languages this would be sufficient in the end of the query: `QUALIFY (RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY rt.incidentnbr, CAST(date_of_event AS DATE) ORDER BY date_of_event DESC)=1`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I'm trying the query now - I'm going to need to do some reading on this, using any conditional logic like Case When is completely new to me-- having an example applied to a problem I'm working on I think is going to be hugely helpful.  The output here looks like the incidentnbr, opendate, closedate if there is one, and most recent resolver - ultimately I will need to have this data as 'snapshots', what were the contents on a per-day basis.  While I'm still trying to figure out how this is working, it looks like it may not output that result?

Comment: To add - the way I'm running that query now, I run it on a loop, so I end up with one record per resolver per day showing the contents of the resolver.  Then I put it all in a pivot table to get a rolling day-by-day view of what each resolver looked like.  Again, hugely gratefuly for the help you've already given, I'm still running the query (May have gotten stuck) and trying to figure out how that Case When works and what exactly it is doing.  (edit - the query runs but does appear to time out.  Still working on it)

Comment: You're welcome. Try removing the second LEFT JOIN section (and ,most_recent.new_resolver_group from first SELECT).

Comment: CASE WHEN is like IF/ELSE logic. When used in SELECT, you derive a new field with a certain logic. For example, when date equals '2013-12-31', then show a record or give out a string/number, else show empty value (CASE WHEN date='2013-12-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END columnname).

In my given solution I searched for closed and opened dates, and only gave out records when found the dates (else the records will show empty)... and to not take in any empty rows as the result, I used aggregation (MAX function.. you can also use MIN there, doesn't matter, since there's one close or open date anyway).

Comment: play around with the subqueries individually.

Comment: That suggestion worked -- so the CASE WHEN and Cast statements apply to the output if and only if it finds data for them, so it will always find one opened record and may or may not find a closed.  The output would be perfect if it could 1.) Filter in a WHERE all data after a given date (Since I'm running this on a loop to get views from multiple days) and 2.) Attach the most recent new_resolver_group to the output given it meets that where condition.  I'm going to keep working on it --